# page loading message in iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

How can i display a "Page is loading" message(using jquery) in an iframe so that the end-user is not looking at a blank page while the actual page is trying to load?

Comment: Why you must use iframe?

Comment: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading.html

Comment: Got it from..http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1081/show-loading-image-when-iframe-loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to you that instead of using iframe, you make absolute or fixed positioned div (maybe even overlay over whole screen) and message in it, on the top of your body. Then, in $(document).ready function add

```
$("div#myMessageDivID").remove();
```

Example:

```
<body>
<div id="loadingMessage" style="position:fixed; background:white; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;" >
<div style="position:relative; width:10%; left:45%; top:45%; color:black;">
Please wait, loading...
</div>
</div>
...
</body>

<script type="text/javascript>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#loadingMessage").remove();
});
</script>
```

You can also use $(body).ready instead of $(document), if your message is removed to early, or postpone removing using setTimeout.

Comment: Got it....http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1081/show-loading-image-when-iframe-loads

Comment: there is no $(body).ready. .ready() only works on $(document)

Comment: Just because it works now doesnt mean it will always work. From the docs: "The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted."

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easiest solution for above problem.**

Place the following code in the head section of page within script tags:

```
function hideProgress(){ 
    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

Place the following code inside the iframe tag:

```
onload="hideProgress()"
```

Place the text message as follows:  Pls insert <> where ever necessary.
div  Page loading. Please wait...  iframe  /iframe  /div

The text message can be replaced with image using img tags.

If the above is not clear and if you want more parameters like width, height, font size, font color, background color, etc. then try the following.

Get this one line code that works on all major browsers at:
http://www.abyzco.in/jokes/jokes-codes.html

I have placed this code on my blog which you can verify at:
http://www.modest-jokes.blogspot.in

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Code to be placed in head section:

<script type="text/javascript"> function hideProgress(){ document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none'; } </script>

Code to be placed in body section:

<div><p id="loader" style="text-align:center;">Clean Jokes loading. <br />Please wait...</p><iframe  style="background-color: #111; border-radius:10px; border:2px solid red;" src="http://www.abyzco.in/assets/sharejokes/01.html"  width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" onload="hideProgress()"></iframe></div>